# WSO2 API Manager SOAP basic authorization (in wso2 layer) not working properly

Tags: soap, wso2, basic-authentication, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to publish SOAP APIs in WSO2 using the endpoint security scheme. I am using it as basic authorization and putting in credentials, but it seems to not be calling the backend API with those creds. Right now I can as a workaround pass in the basic auth headers *myself*, along with an Oauth2 token (in the header) to hit the published API in the store.
Am I just going about this wrong?

Using WSO2 API Manager 1.6

EDIT: I have replicated this issue in WSO2 API MANAGER 1.8. Viewing the packets in wireshark, it is making the request without adding the authorization. Restful calls with embedded authentication on the WSO2 layer seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish SOAP/REST APi's in WSO2 API Manager. You need to pass in the username password, along with the Authorization header which is base64 encoding (consumer key:consumer secret), You can follow the blog post [1] on how to consume a SOAP API & [2] for more information on tokens.

[1] http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/07/consuming-soap-service-using-wso2-api.html

[2] http://lalajisureshika.blogspot.com/2012/11/generate-application-tokens-user-tokens.html

The above blog [1] &[2] refers to a API Manager older release, hence you will need to refer to  WSO2 API manager 1.6 releases documents [3] for API key generation etc.. However, to find out how to publish SOAP API's you could use the blog pointed out.

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160

Comment: Yes I am able to publish SOAP API's in WSO2-AM. I published a SOAP API and when you give it a WSDL, there is a dropdown that lets you make the endpoint secure. I did that and gave it credentials. When I use the published API from the store, it is never passing along those credentials. When I observe the packets with wireshark on the WSO2-AM server, I can see it is not passing along those credentials.

When I look in the ESB Configuration source, I can plainly see the the credentials within the API.

Comment: And also, I was able to replicate this in WSO2-AM version 1.8